How the forces act in a bent member of a Truss?

As in the attached image, sometimes, the members of a Truss are bent, in this particular case, the member AD and BC together form a semicircle. According to me intuitively, the forces in the bent members at a point should be tangential to the member at that point. If my intuition is correct, then the force on the pin A by member AD should be perpendicular to AC. And hence the Y component of the force by pin A on member AD should be equal to the force exerted by member AD onto the pin A. But according to the solution given in the book this intuition is wrong. In the given solution the force by member AD on pin A is given to act along the straight line joining A and D. I am not able to convince myself that the logic in the solution given. Please provide some additional insights, so that the given solution is intuitive to me.

Notice that at joint $B$, the members $AB$ and $BC$ are collinear. Since the resultant of forces from $AB$ and $BC$ must be in the horizontal direction, $BD$ cannot exert a vertical force on $B$ if it is in equilibrium, i.e. $BD$ is a zero-force member.
This implies that joint $D$ cannot exert forces on $AD$ or $DC$, making $AD$ a simple two-force member. As a general rule, the forces at the ends of a two-force member are along the line joining the ends. If this was not the case, there would be a net force on $AD$ and it could not be in equilibrium (the tangent at joint $A$ is vertical, and the tangent at joint $D$ is horizontal; these two could not cancel out if we go by your assumption).
